# Почему не загружаться подпункты меню joomla! 3?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Меню ведет себя аномально. Дочерние подпункты второго уровня видны только при переходе по ссылке на родительский элемент первого уровня. Второй раз такое случается на двух независимо разрабатываемых сайтах. Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: Два раза из двух - это симптоматика... может, так и должно быть?

Comment: Было бы неплохо сайты приложить

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov второй сайт я как то выправил. Он сейчас работает, но я вообще не могу предположить что я с ним сделал. Тот сайт на котором сейчас это проявляется находиться на локальном хосте. Завтра загружу его на сервер и скину ссылку. Спасибо за ваше внимание 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблем заключается в стилях вашего шаблона, приведу пример: предположим у вас строение меню

```
<ul>
<li><a>Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a>Menu 2</a>
<ul>
<li>Submenu</li>
<li>Submenu</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a>Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

По стандарту всем родительским  `LI` даётся класс `deeper parent`, а вот дочерним `UL` в стилях прописывается `display:none;` , при переходе на ссылку `Menu 2` данный `LI` получает новый класс 'active' и по всей вероятности у вас в стилях прописанно

```
li.active ul{
display:block;
}
```

и по этой причине вы видите открытими субменю при входе на родительскую ссылку.Если хотите продотвратить показ всех дочерних меню, найдите и отредактируйте стили.

> Обновлено

Или же зайдите в модуль меню, посмотрите в настройках какие значения поставленны
1.Start Level 
2. Show Sub-menu Items Yes/No

Comment: В DOM пункты не отображаться. Т.е. их не загружает из базы.

Comment: т.е на других страницах в HTML у меню нет дочерних меню, а когда находитесь в родительском меню, данные пункты показывает в HTML ?

Comment: Да. Это действительно аномально)

Comment: Вы стандатрный модуль меню используйте? или сторонний?

Зайдите в модуль меню, посмотрите в настройках какие значения поставленны
1.Start Level
2. Show Sub-menu Items  Yes/No

Comment: Я не думал что всё будет так просто. Спасибо!!!

Comment: Пожалуйста, всегда рад помочь! )